# create complex table from the Json data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON that looks like this

```
[
{
    "teacher": "teacher1",
    "student": "student1"
    },
{
   "teacher": "teacher1",
    "student": "student1"
    },
{
    "teacher": "teacher1",
    "student": "student1"
    },
{
    "teacher": "teacher2",
    "student": "student1"
    },
{
   "teacher": "teacher2",
    "student": "student2"
    }
]
```

I want to convert it in a way that it shows me the count for each teacher  like this

```
[
    {
        "teacherName": "teacher1",
        "teacherCount": "3"
    },
    {
        "teacherName": "teacher2",
        "teacherCount": "2"
    },
]
```

I am working on a node project where I need to print this data in a table.

Comment: Are the students irrelevant? Are you asking for the conversion or the (presumably HTML) table? How is this related to jQuery? Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods. Googling `js count property array of objects` yields insights.

Comment: I might want to use student data in the future.  If I can crack it with teacher then I can do the rest with the student as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a Map (using `.reduce()`), which is indexed/keyed by the `teacher` value. The value stored at the teacher is the count of the number of times that teacher has been seen in your array of objects. You can then use `Array.from()` with the `Map` built using reduce to get each key-value pair from the map (where the key is the teacherName and value is the teacherCount). To get each key-value pair, you can use the mapping function of Array.from() and map each key-value ([key, value]) to an object like so:

```js
const data = [{ "teacher": "teacher1", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "teacher1", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "teacher1", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "teacher2", "student": "student1" }, { "teacher": "teacher2", "student": "student2" } ];

const res = Array.from(data.reduce((map, {teacher}) => {
  return map.set(teacher, (map.get(teacher) || 0) + 1);
}, new Map), ([teacherName, teacherCount]) => ({teacherName, teacherCount}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Well done, seems you beat me and you made use of `Map`

Answer (score 0):

You can collect your counts into a unique set using `reduce`, incrementing the teacher  if it exists, otherwise initiating it to 1.  Then an example of how to format follows using `map`.

```js
let data = getData();

let teachers = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (val.teacher in acc)
    acc[val.teacher]++;
  else
    acc[val.teacher] = 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

let formatted = Object.entries(teachers).map(
  ([teacherName, teacherCount]) => ({ teacherName, teacherCount })
);

console.log(formatted);


/*****************************************************************/
function getData() {
  return [{
      "teacher": "teacher1",
      "student": "student1"
    },
    {
      "teacher": "teacher1",
      "student": "student1"
    },
    {
      "teacher": "teacher1",
      "student": "student1"
    },
    {
      "teacher": "teacher2",
      "student": "student1"
    },
    {
      "teacher": "teacher2",
      "student": "student2"
    }
  ]
}
```