# create complex table from the JSON data for multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON that looks like this

```
[{
                "teacher": "teacher1",
                "student": "student1",
                "segment": "product"
            },
            {
                "teacher": "teacher1",
                "student": "student1",
                "segment": "UNR"
            },
            {
                "teacher": "teacher1",
                "student": "student1",
                "segment": "product"
            },
            {
                "teacher": "teacher2",
                "student": "student1",
                "segment": "UNR"
            },
            {
                "teacher": "teacher2",
                "student": "student2",
                "segment": "product"
            }
        ]
```

With the help of [create complex table from the Json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61263480/create-complex-table-from-the-json-data) i can create an array counting each teacher and its count by I want to add another detail in it now. I want to calculate the instance of the segment for each teacher as well like below

```
[
    {
        "teacherName": "teacher1",
        "teacherCount": "3",
        "productCount":"2",
        "unrCount":"1"
    },
    {
        "teacherName": "teacher2",
        "teacherCount": "2",
        "productCount":"1",
        "unrCount":"1"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `reduce` to loop thru the array. Use `teacher` as the key to summarize the data into an object. Use `Object.values` to convert object into an array.

```js
const data = [{"teacher":"teacher1","student":"student1","segment":"product"},{"teacher":"teacher1","student":"student1","segment":"UNR"},{"teacher":"teacher1","student":"student1","segment":"product"},{"teacher":"teacher2","student":"student1","segment":"UNR"},{"teacher":"teacher2","student":"student2","segment":"product"}]

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((c, {teacher,segment}) => {
  c[teacher] = c[teacher] || {"teacherName": teacher,"teacherCount": 0,"productCount": 0,"unrCount": 0};
  c[teacher].teacherCount++;

  if (segment === "product") c[teacher].productCount++;
  if (segment === "UNR") c[teacher].unrCount++;

  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

let say d is your json, then this code will work.

```
d.reduce((s, i)=>{
    teacher=i["teacher"]
    t=(s[teacher]==null)?{teacherCount:0}:s[teacher]
    seg=i['segment']
    t[seg]=(t[seg]==null)?1:(t[seg]+1)
    t["teacherCount"]+=1
    s[teacher]=t
    return s
},{})
```